# Why didn't the Seven Kingdoms know about the Dells?

Tags: seven-kingdoms

In the Seven Kingdoms series by Kristin Cashore, there are two regions, separated by highly inhospitable mountains: the Seven Kingdoms, whence Katsa hails; and the Dells (?), which is where Leck visited before he came back and took over.

On the one hand, there seems to have been essentially no knowledge on the part of the Seven Kingdoms of the Dells,  until Leck and his father stumbled into there—though the reverse wasn't so true, but that happened relatively recently in the story's timeline.

On the other hand, getting between the two isn't *that* hard, however nasty the mountains are: Katsa did it, as did the delegation in *Bitterblue* (who don't have her survival skills), the latter of which included a middle-aged ambassador, and even Larch, with little preparation and equipment and a  child, managed to get through. Furthermore, the presence of humans in both areas seems to suggest some past connection, as do the intriguing similarities between monsters and Gracelings. As we know from our own world, if humans can cross a barrier, no matter how inhospitable, they tend to do so (for instance, the Polynesian settlement of Hawai'i).

What accounts for the near total lack of knowledge that the Seven Kingdoms have of the Dells? Was there some knowledge or trade in the past, and if so, how was it lost? Has there been much less time for people to try getting across the mountains than one would assume?